# Replace heredoc syntax

Tags: php, html, syntax, heredoc

Im new to php and I have a templating system in which I orignally used heredoc syntax but have since decided to get rid of it for a number of reasons.

I have something that looks like this:

```
    public function display_admin() {

    return <<<ADMIN_FORM

    <form action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <label for="title">Title:</label><br />
      <input name="title" id="title" type="text" maxlength="220" />
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <label for="bodytext">Body Text:</label><br />
      <textarea name="bodytext" id="bodytext"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Create This Entry!" />
    </form>

    ADMIN_FORM; }
```

And I call it on a page using this:

```
$obj = new myCMS();
echo $obj->display_admin();
```

How can I replace the heredoc syntax? Is there another efficient method for inserting large blocks of HTML into a PHP function? I know there must be a simple solution, here but every time I google it, I get answers that seem better suited for inserting single lines of HTML, not whole blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there are not much reasons for inserting large blocks of HTML into a PHP function.
calling `$obj->display_admin();` makes not much sense.
while

```
$data = array('bodytext' => $text);
$obj->set_data($data);
$obj->set_template('admin_form')
$obj->display();
```

makes.

Next, heredoc is absolutely not a templating solution.
While PHP itself is.

So, make a file `admin_form.tpl.php`

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <label for="title">Title:</label><br />
  <input name="title" id="title" type="text" maxlength="220" />
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <label for="bodytext">Body Text:</label><br />
  <textarea name="bodytext" id="bodytext"><?=$data['bodytext']?></textarea>
<? if ($data['id']): ?>
  <input name="id" id="id" type="hidden" value="<?=$data['id']?>" />
<? endif ?>
  <input type="submit" value="Create This Entry!" />
</form>
```

and just include it where it fits - most likely in your templating class.

Answer (score 3):

HEREDOCS are the only practical choice of multi-line text building of this sort. Your only other options would be to line-by-line concatenation, or "break" out of PHP mode and use some output buffering.

```
$text = "blah blah blah";
$text .= "blah blah blah";
$text .= "blah blah blah";

ob_start(); ?>
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
<? $text = ob_get_clean(); 

$text = <<<EOL
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
EOL;
```

Of the 3, heredocs are far more useable. You don't have to worry about escaping quotes within the text body, and with variable functions, you can even do function calls within the text now to do stuff like `htmlspecialchars()` calls without having to pre-define any such text outside the heredoc block.

```
$formfield = htmlspecialchars($_POST['somefield']);
$txt = <<<EOL
<input type="text" value="$formfield" />
EOL;
```

vs.

```
$hsc = function($x) { return htmlspecialchars($x); };

$txt = <<<EOL
<input type="text" value="{$hsc($_POST['somefield'])}" />
EOL;
```

---

comment followup:

Nothing says you can't concatenate heredocs:

```
$txt = <<<EOL
blah blah blah
EOL;

$txt .= <<<EOL
more blah
EOL;
```

After all, a heredoc simply produces a string that happens to have multiple lines of text in it. You can split the monolithic single heredoc into two or more sections and put your conditional `if()` stuff in between the two.

On the other hand, with the variable functions, you can trivially whip one up to insert the conditional text within a single heredoc:

```
$conditional = function($parameter) { return (($parameter == 1) ? 'Success' : 'Failure'); }

$txt = <<EOL
Your login attempt
resulted in {$conditional($somevalue)}.
How does that make you feel?
EOL;
```

v.s.

```
$txt = <<<EOL
Your login attemp
resulted in
EOL;
$txt .= (($somevalue == 1) ? 'Success' : 'Failure');
$txt .= <<<EOL
.
How does that make you feel?
EOL;
```

Comment: The issue is that I need to toss in some 'if' statements in the middle of heredoc to report successful posting, etc... How is that usually handled? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: @Thomas oh great. this issue is exact reason for me saying heredoc is not a choice for templating!

Comment: Never mind the fact that PHP is a template language, so would you like a template for your template while you template another template? very "Inception"-like - always another level deeper...